# How to search new line char in oracle table?

Tags: sql, oracle, newline

I have an issue with a file that's created from data (in format of bytes) returned from the database.
the problem is that there is a few newlines in the file.
i would like to know if there is a way to write a where clause to check if some record has a newline character?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using the CHR function to look for the ASCII value:

```
select *
from your_table
where instr(your_text_col, chr(10)) > 0;
```

If you want to search for carriage returns, that would be chr(13).

Answer (score 9):

You can write something like:

```
SELECT id
  FROM table_name
 WHERE field_name LIKE '%'||CHR(10)||'%'
;
```

(`||` is the concatenation operator; `CHR(10)` is the tenth ASCII character, i.e. a newline.)

Comment: Thanks. i found another way: `select * from label_master where regexp_like (text, chr(10))`

Comment: Computationally regex functions are usually more expensive than their non-regex equivalents. Therefore it is good practice to only use `regexp_like()` etc when we actually need the power of regular expression matching.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the platform, a newline will generally either be a `CHR(10)` (Unix) or a `CHR(13)` followed by a `CHR(10)` (Windows).  There are other options for other more esoteric platforms, but 99.999% of the time, it will be one of these two.

You can search the data in a column looking for one or both characters

```
SELECT instr( column_name, CHR(10) ) position_of_first_lf,
       instr( column_name, CHR(13) || CHR(10) ) position_of_first_cr_lf
  FROM table_name
 WHERE instr( column_name, CHR(10) ) > 0
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked the best for me.

select * from label_master where regexp_like (text, chr(10));

Comment: Computationally regex functions are usually more expensive than their non-regex equivalents. Therefore it is good practice to only use `regexp_like()` etc when we actually need the power of regular expression matching.