# Oracle - Query to return first line of a value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Queries.

how I can write a query to pull only the first line from value?

**Example -**

```
select address 
  from user 
 where id =1;
```

Sample Output (Single row & not 3 rows)

```
Anthony Benoit
490 E Main Street
Norwich CT 06360
```

I would like to get only the first line,
which is `Anthony Benoit`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask], and update your question.  As it is now, your question is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for your warm welcome, I have updated the question, please take a look now

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SUBSTR` and index on the first `new-line` character something like this

```
select substr(lines,0,instr(lines,chr(10))) d
from
(select 'line 1
line2' lines
from dual)
```

Pay attention to `chr(10)` you most likely gonna need to improve that part to support different new line chars (e.g. chr(13), chr(13) and chr(10)...etc)

Comment: This link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482235/how-to-search-new-line-char-in-oracle-table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your example output are three rows.

If you are on 11g and prior, Just add `select * from ... where rownum = 1` in the outer query to your posted query, but you also need to have `order by column` in your inner query.

If you are on 12c, you can simply use ROW LIMIT clause, just add this clause `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY`.

Comment: Hi, No this is a single row output

Comment: Well, then the `SUBSTR` solution would suffice.