# sql: select rows with multiple lines of data

Tags: sql, oracle11g, toad

In `table A` -> `Column X` there is some data which has numbers, alphabets and special characters. Most of the records has single line of data but some of them has 2 or 3 lines of data.

```
1 this is a sample description of data 01/11/2017 @ 123'~
```

Records with two lines of data

```
1 this is a sample description
2 of data 22/11/2017 @~ 12@#'
```

I need to do a select query to get the records which has 2 lines of data in Column X of table A.

I use `TOAD` and the above mentioned sample data is from the `Grid popup editor`

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select those rows that contain a new line (do not know your sample data, either `chr(10)` or `chr(13)`):

```
select *
from tableA
where instr(columnX, chr(10)) > 0;
```

The solution is taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13482317/2630032), please do not forget to upvote the linked solution if it helped you.

Comment: This works perfectly. i upvoted the original post too. thank you